# Django DB with foreign keys and 3nf

Tags: python, django

I have a simple DB structure:

```
Category
    + id (pk)
    + name (String)
    + description (String)

Software
    + id (pk)
    + name (String)
    + description (String)
    + (removed for brevity)

SoftwareCategory
    + sid (FK to Software)
    + cid (FK to Category)
```

My conundrum that I'm facing is that I don't know how to represent that as models within django *and* still be able to use inline models and forms for editing and creating the data.  I can toss an `FK to Software` on the `Category` table but that means I'm storing all the categories many times -- vice versa for putting a `FK to Category` on the `Software` table.

Essentially I would like the above structure but be able to reference the models in the admin and form sides as such:

```
class CategoryInlineAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Category # omitted for brevity

@admin.register(Software)
class SoftwareAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = Software # omitted for brevity
    inlines = [CategoryInlineAdmin]
```

I do not know how to be able to keep my "joiner" table (`SoftwareCategory`) while referencing the models through the convenience of Django's interface.

Comment: Would the best way to do this is to build the forms inline, but override the `save()` method to add the foreign keys in the joiner table that match the software to it's one/many categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The documentation for [manytomanyfields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany) was a bit opaque to me and after working through it and another example I was able to figure out what I needed to do with the [inline admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models) stuff.